# Openshift Mymsql persistent storage won't mount on php

Tags: openshift

I have pod that utilizes php and I have a persistent MySQL storage created on openshift online. Whenever I click the option "add storage to php" and I set mysql as the storage with mount point /var/lib/mysql the server attempts to redeploy but the new container is stuck creating and then fails. I get multiple error messages like this one:

```
Failed to attach volume "pvc-d4962378-aae0-11e7-8a41-0a2a2b777307" on node "ip-172-31-50-169.us-west-2.compute.internal" with: Error attaching EBS volume "vol-0087ade77401256f5" to instance "i-0b8b81e68bc629f01": VolumeInUse: vol-0087ade77401256f5 is already attached to an instance status code: 400, request id: dfbdac9b-bad0-4211-8158-080a4e120b1a. The volume is currently attached to instance "i-02a6b44c53ab0d7f2"
```

Isn't this the proper way to connect mysql storage to a pod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EBS volume type can only be mounted on one node at a time in an OpenShift cluster. When you have PHP and MySQL as separate applications that can land on different nodes and as a result, you can't mount the persistent volume against both. The error is warning you of this.

The only way you can use a single EBS volume against PHP and MySQL at the same time is for them to be running in separate containers of the same pod. You also need to ensure that the deployment strategy is set to Recreate and not Rolling, as rolling results in a new instance being created when the old still exists, with same issue arising as the new and old could be on different nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it makes a lot more sense. Any chance you could include instructions on how to create a php and mysql container and include them under the same pod? Not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: Doing it using the web console or using ``oc `` is rather fiddly. You really need to create the raw resource objects as JSON/YAML directly or via a template. See the templates marked for ``testing`` in the ``templates`` directory at https://github.com/openshift-evangelists/wordpress-quickstart

Comment: For a better template, specifically designed to deploy arbitrary PHP application code as PHP+MySQL in one pod with single volume, see templates in https://github.com/openshift-evangelists/php-quickstart Use ``oc create -f mysql-persistent-single-volume.json`` on the template file, then select from catalog browser under PHP. Enter in the repo URL for your application as source repository. Volume for PHP application mounted as ``/opt/app-root/data``.

Comment: The second link does not work but the answers helped me move forward with my question. I have a follow up but I will open a new questions since it is more complex.

Comment: Are you saying the ``php-quickstart`` link doesn't work? I follow it and it goes to GitHub no problem.